# Run C server and client files in CLion at the same time

Tags: c, server, client, clion

I'm currently taking a Data Networks class and ***[need to run a local server and client at the same time using CLion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTOoC.png)***. I'm very unfamiliar with the CLion so I might not fully understand if the answer isn't given super basic.

***How do I run both at the same time and give them each their own arguments?*** I need the client to give the server a username and password, receive a message, shut down and then be able to reconnect to the server. Included is a screenshot of them running in two different windows and the arguments needed.

Included is a link to my file of what I'm trying to do in CLion but I used Cygwin.

Comment: according to the linked screen shots (DON'T USE LINKED SCREEN SHOTS, copy and paste the screen text directly into the question.)  both applications are running at the same time, one in each of two terminal windows.  So exactly what is the problem?

Comment: you could try running two instances of Clion, one instance in each of two terminal windows.

Comment: Just as a heads up,  a server (in general) should not exit after every transaction with a client.  Rather it should loop, back to the 'accept()' function call.  Even better would be for the server to use `pthread_create()` to pass off the handling of the client transactions, so the server could loop back to the 'accept() function immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the CMakeLists.txt file you need to add both files as executables.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(Project_2_2)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES
        cmake-build-debug/stockList.txt
        VonBusch-p1c.c
        VonBusch-p1s.c)

include_directories(.)

#add_executable(Project_2_2 ${SOURCE_FILES})

add_executable(Client VonBusch-p1c.c)
add_executable(Server VonBusch-p1s.c)
```

And then in the top right of CLion, select each executable and hit the Run. This allows you to run both files at the same time.